# Bootstrap and Carousel

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I have checked possibilities and issues with frameworks. Bootstrap has additional code and some code need to be modified.
I enclose my code CSS and I kindly ask you to check and inform me if this is correct, specially position elements.

```
.carousel {
    height: 250px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.carousel-caption {
    z-index: 20;
}
.carousel-caption {
    left: 10%;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    right: 10%;
}
.carousel .item {
    height: 250px;
}
.carousel-inner > .item > img {
    height: 250px;
    left: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
}
.carousel-control {
    width: 5%;
}
.carousel-control.left, .carousel-control.right {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 250px;
    width: 5%;
}
.carousel-control.left {
    background: url("../images/left1.png") no-repeat scroll center center rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
.carousel-control.right {
    background: url("../images/right1.png") no-repeat   scroll center center rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
.carousel-indicators {
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 40%;
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin-left: -20%;
    padding-left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    width: 50%;
    z-index: 15;
}
```

Comment: Please upload your code on Jsfiddle.

Comment: so what's the issue? and what exactly you wanted to position and how? use bootply.com to play with bootstrap